# Types of property 'licenses' are incompatible. Type 'License[]' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts in getServerSideProps using iron-session?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I get the following error with red-squiggly lines on the `async` word:

```
Argument of type '({ req, res }: GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>) => Promise<{ props: { admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }; } | { ...; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(context: GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>) => GetServerSidePropsResult<{ admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }> | Promise<...>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ props: { admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }; } | { props: { admin: Admin; licenses: License[]; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSidePropsResult<{ admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }> | Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<{ admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }>>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ props: { admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }; } | { props: { admin: Admin; licenses: License[]; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<{ admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }>>'.
      Type '{ props: { admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }; } | { props: { admin: Admin; licenses: License[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSidePropsResult<{ admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }>'.
        Type '{ props: { admin: Admin; licenses: License[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'GetServerSidePropsResult<{ admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }>'.
          Type '{ props: { admin: Admin; licenses: License[]; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ props: { admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; } | Promise<{ admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }>; }'.
            Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
              Type '{ admin: Admin; licenses: License[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; } | Promise<{ admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }>'.
                Type '{ admin: Admin; licenses: License[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ admin: Admin; licenses?: undefined; }'.
                  Types of property 'licenses' are incompatible.
                    Type 'License[]' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2345)
```

My `license.tsx` file looks like:

## pages/license.tsx

```
export const getServerSideProps = withSessionSsr(async function ({ req, res }) {
    const admin = req.session.admin
    const licenses = await prisma.license.findMany()

    if (admin === undefined) {
        res.setHeader('location', '/admin')
        res.statusCode = 302
        res.end()
        return {
            props: {
                admin: { isLoggedIn: false } as Admin,
            },
        }
    }

    return {
        props: { admin, licenses },
    }
})
```

My `withSession.ts` file looks like:

## utils/withSession.ts

```
import { GetServerSidePropsContext, GetServerSidePropsResult, NextApiHandler } from 'next'
import { withIronSessionApiRoute, withIronSessionSsr } from 'iron-session/next'

import { IRON_OPTIONS } from '@/utils/index'

function withSessionRoute(handler: NextApiHandler) {
    return withIronSessionApiRoute(handler, IRON_OPTIONS)
}

// Theses types are compatible with InferGetStaticPropsType https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#typescript-use-getstaticprops
function withSessionSsr<P extends { [key: string]: unknown } = { [key: string]: unknown }>(
    handler: (
        context: GetServerSidePropsContext
    ) => GetServerSidePropsResult<P> | Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<P>>
) {
    return withIronSessionSsr(handler, IRON_OPTIONS)
}

export { withSessionRoute, withSessionSsr }
```

How do I solve this? My goal is to want the `props` to not only return `{ admin }` but also any other objects, in this case, `license` without fiddling with the `utils` file since it's a session wrapper to check if some page is private or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the `licenses: undefined` in the 1st `if` statement to `licenses: []` to make the error go away:

## pages/license.tsx

```
export const getServerSideProps = withSessionSsr(async function ({ req, res }) {
    const admin = req.session.admin
    const licenses = await prisma.license.findMany()

    if (admin === undefined) {
        res.setHeader('location', '/admin')
        res.statusCode = 302
        res.end()
        return {
            props: {
                admin: { isLoggedIn: false } as Admin,
                licenses: [],
            },
        }
    }

    return {
        props: { admin, licenses },
    }
})
```